# Error when I upload an image

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Cant upload an image to server...

Here is the code:

```
let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1)

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "avatar_image")
    },
    to: url,
    method: .put,
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
      upload.responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
      }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
      print(encodingError)
    }
})
```

if change `data` to `let data = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "flag", withExtension: "png")!` it uploads this image to server.

Why it cant upload image from my photo library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why but I had to upload a file url. So I wrote the file to disk and then upload it...

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.5)
    try! UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.5)?.write(to: imagePath!)
    profileImageURL = imagePath

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(profileImageURL, withName: "avatar_image")},
        to: "https://api.booze.kz/v1/customers/\(phoneNumber)",
        method: .put,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                 upload.responseJSON { response in
                     debugPrint(response)
                 }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                 print(encodingError)
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try original instead of Edited

```
let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

Comment: check the image extension it may be jpeg convert it , use **info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]**

Comment: it doesnt matter jpeg or png... and UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata works only with camera, i need with photolibrary

Comment: print it also for image from main , also try **UIImagePNGRepresentation**